# How to add CSS properties with JavaScript without style attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles

I am creating custom HTML tags. I want to know if was possible to add CSS properties to HTML tags with JavaScript without adding, use css file or appear the "style" attribute on the HTML tag, example:

*NO:*

```html
<-my-tag style="color:red">STACKOVERFLOW</-my-tag>
```

**YES:**

```html
<-my-tag>STACKOVERFLOW</-my-tag>
```

[And the result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvBjx.jpg)

Comment: You can do it with global css targeting your tag.

Comment: [Custom element names can't start with a dash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements)

Comment: why don't you want the style attribute to appear ?

Comment: How exactly is JavaScript involved?  If you have a reference to the DOM element in your JavaScript code then can't you just set properties on its `.style` property?

Comment: could you answer our comments instead of adding condition to the original question each time someone tries to answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a style element in DOM and append anything to it which will automatically apply to your element

```
const appendStyle = (customStyles) => {
    const styleEl = document.createElement('style');
    styleEl.innterHTML = `yourTagName {${customStyles}}`;
    document.body.appendChild(styleEl);
}

appendStyle('background-color: red; font-size: 15');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can either add a separate `.css` file and place there your styles.

Like `style.css`

```css
yourTagName {
   color: red;
}
```

And then include it within the `<head></head>` section of HTML using `<link>` or you could add your styles within the `<style>` tag in the `<head>` section as well.

Check [W3 HTML Styles - CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp) to learn more.